# How to inspect modal text with Cuprite?

Tags: capybara, cuprite

I'm switching from the [Poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) to [Cuprite](https://github.com/machinio/cuprite) driver for [Capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara).

I have Javascript code which sets the message for a confirmation modal which I want to check in my feature specs.

The javascript is `confirm("....")`.

With Poltergiest I could do `page.driver.browser.modal_message`.

This is unsupported by Cuprite, it there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybaras `accept_confirm`  (which cuprite supports) returns the string from the system modal:

```
text = accept_confirm do
   # ... the actions that triggers the modal to appear
end
```

Or you can pass a string to `accept_confirm` to have it verify the string:

```
accept_confirm('the text to check') do
   # ... the actions that triggers the modal to appear
end
```

Comment: Much better, thanks. Will accept if nothing else appears.

Comment: @Kris note - using that should also work with any other driver designed for Capybara (selenium, apparition, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [ferrum](https://github.com/route/ferrum) driver which Cuprite uses under the hood I can see it is possible register a hook for a dialog appearing.

```
message = nil

page.driver.browser.on(:dialog) do |dialog|
  message = dialog.message
end

accept_confirm do
  click_on progress_tab.name      
  expect(message).to eq text('...')
end
```

It isn't pretty.